# Spread operator in React .setState() in the useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Why is the spread operator used in `setName()` function how does it work. *What this code does* is it takes the input from the user and displays it on the screen but before using spread operator the displayed values gets erased when user entered a value in the other input field. First Name gets erased when last name was entered **why did this happen** and when using spread operator it provides the previous value and the code works perfect *I want to know the logic behind this*.

```js
import React from "react";

const Count2 = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState({ firstName: " ", lastName: " " });
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name.firstName}
        onChange={(e) => setName({ ...name, firstName: e.target.value })}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name.lastName}
        onChange={(e) => setName({ ...name, lastName: e.target.value })}
      />
      <h2>Your first Name is - {name.firstName}</h2>
      <h2>Your first Name is - {name.lastName}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Count2;
```

Comment: yes it works fine i just want to know how that spread operator works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, It's not any different from what spread operator does anywhere else which is:

```
const name1 = {firstname: "x", lastName:"y", age: 27}
```

imagine you want to make a copy od the name1 object. you could say:

```
const name2 = {...name1}
```

which means you would get a copy of all the properties of the object.
now imagine you want to override only one property in that object, then you would do:

```
const name2 = {...name1, lastName: name1.lastname.toUpperCase()}
```

which means you first copy all the properties & at the end you overWrite lastName property with something else (in my example the uppercase version of the same copied object).

in the react code you are setting the state to a copy of it (so you wouldn't change other properties) and then you overwrite your specified property of the state object to what the user has typed into the input. so everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Spread syntax can be used when all elements from an object or array need to be included in a list of some kind.

```
Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected
```

[Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)